# How to map complex URLs

Tags: web-services, rest, soa

It's easy to map stuff like this to a method.  Below shows examples of URI Templates and related mapped methods in the back-end service or mvc controller:

```
/Cars/
Get()

/Cars/{id}
Get(int id)
```

But what if you have more than just that.  Lets say you have this:

```
/Cars/{id}/seat/{id}
```

So I am saying I want to target one of the seats in this care (I know bad example but this is all I could think of for the moment).

So I want a seat, and seat is at the end which tells use the resource I'm asking for.

I want to know how someone would map this back to a controller (or service) and related method.

I'm thinking since you want seat, the Seat Service or controller would have I guess something like this:

```
Seat (service)
```

- Get() - gets all seats, maps to /seats/
- GetSeatByCarId(int id) - this would I think match my url above, maybe we strip out whatever is before `/seat/` like the car id?  I don't know, that's what I'm asking, ways I can do this.

What do people do when the url has more than just a `[resource]/[id]`?  How do you manage that and what does it look like in the backend, what kind of method and how are you mapping these more complicated URI templates?